# android - my project files get corrupt when I open the project android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've worked on a project , everything was ok the last time I was working on , now after 2 month I reopen the project in android studio and suddenly , every files is broken . 
file example this is one of the xml layouts :

```
20yk    XhöÙ ›ÿÿ        h          ê2ç ›ÿÿ?×å ›ÿÿ                       Hú˜ä ›ÿÿHú˜ä ›ÿÿ                                                       Key Ø([©F¨`û˜ä ›ÿÿe m \ C ¸           C o         l S e t ý                     $ H 0 3 À¶Aåøÿÿ        20yk    øµ
Ø ›ÿÿ        h        ðªÉâ ›ÿÿPMä ›ÿÿ                       Hû˜ä ›ÿÿHû˜ä ›ÿÿ                                                        FreeØ([©F¨°þöé ›ÿÿ@Úðã ›ÿÿNtFsø([©F¨PœÈÞ ›ÿÿEäå ›ÿÿPÎ è ›ÿÿÿ       t    °Ê®ã ›ÿÿKey ¸([©F¨Àü˜ä ›ÿÿe m \ C ¸           C o         l S e t ý                     " H 0 3 À¶Aåøÿÿ        20yk    øµ
Ø ›ÿÿ        h        @ `è ›ÿÿ0)å ›ÿÿ                       ¨ü˜ä ›ÿÿ¨ü˜ä ›ÿÿ                                                       1RvaL        4             @ý˜ä ›ÿÿ`      h      ¨ÿ˜ä ›ÿÿ ÿ˜ä ›ÿÿ        €  ÐÐÐÐÐÐààðààÐðà‚Ð‡à‚À„À‚àð‚À‚À‡àà‰À†ð‚Àà„Àƒàƒðƒðƒð‹Ð‡ðƒà‡Ðƒà†À†À‡Ðƒàƒà†àðà†ðŒðàƒà¸àµÀœÐšà…à…Ð‰ð‰àÐ›àˆÐ‡ðÐŽÐ‹ððð†À…ÐÐ‚ðð„ÀˆàÐàÀ…ððð™Àƒðà‚Ð‰ð‹À…À‘ðA¿à¥À‡ÐBàÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐB¾àÐƒÀ‚à‚À‚à‚à‚Ð‚À‚Ð‚Ð‹à†ðà„À¢ð¹Ð†à›à‚ÐÀÐ…À„ðA—Ð“ààð¶ÐàC”ð¤ð‰à‘ð‡À‡ÐÀ„ÐŠÐ‡ÀAŽÀÀ…ÀB¢àððƒðA¤ÀF¤ÐÀAÀ™ð™ðŒÀ§ÐÀ«Ð…Ð¾ÀððA¨À…À‡À†ÀC¹À‡àˆÀ‹Ð˜à‰àÐA‘à¡ÐÐ‚ÀÐƒÐÐ‚ÀÀÀ‡À‡à‚À›ðƒà‘À‚Ðð‚Àà‰ÀŠàðIÀð‡à‚ðÀÀ‚àðð‚ÀƒàÐƒÐŠð‰ð„à…ð…ð…Ð‹ÀŠð‰à‰À†à‡ð‡ð‡Ð„à…ð†À…àƒÀƒÐƒÀƒà†Àð„à‡ÐƒÐ†ÐŠÀðð‚ÀðƒÀƒÀ…ðð‚Ðà‚Ð‚à‚à‚Àƒà‚à‚à‚àƒà‚ðƒð‚à‚à‚à‚à‚Ð‚à‚à‚à‚àCƒð‚à„ð
```

I don't know whats going on ,the other projects are ok but this one is broken

could you help me ? why is this happen ? how can I fix this ?

Comment: Can you open this file from the project directory by windows?

Comment: Check the directory of project files using windows explorer..!

Comment: I've checked via windows explorer ,it's the same results

Comment: what is your windows display language setting?

Comment: Looks like its a virus, try running a scan using a good anti-virus software. That should probably help.